# Как определить уровень вложенности категории Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Ситуация такая:
есть категории

```
Каталог
- Уровень 2
-- Уровень 3
--- Запись
```

Как правильно написать условие для category.php,
что бы выводить разный код на каждом из уровней категорий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$current_cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
$child = get_category($current_cat_id);
$level2 = $child->parent;
$child2 = get_category($level2);
$level3 = $child2->parent;

if(is_category(6)){
    include "catalog.php";
} else if ($level2 == 6){
    include "catalog_level2.php";
} else if ($level3 == 6){
    include "catalog_level3.php";
}
```